# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'map' when trying to write a recursive algorithm for a depth limited search

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence

Trying to write a recursive algorithm for a depth limited search for a 6-puzzle game but for some reason i keep getting the above error and cannot understand why.
This is my code for the recursve depth limited search:

```
def rec_dls(node, limit):
    global cutoff_occurred
    cutoff = 0
    failure = -1
    if goal_state == node.state:
        return node
    elif limit == 0:
        return cutoff          # cutoff
    else:
        cutoff_occurred = False
        actions = moves(node.state) # all possibles children of this state
        for action in actions:
            child = State(action, node, node.depth+1, node.cost+1)
            result = rec_dls(child, limit - 1)
            if result == cutoff:
                cutoff_occurred = True
            elif result != failure:
                return result
        if cutoff_occurred:
            return cutoff
        else:
            return failure
        

def dls(limit):
    node = State(initial_state, None, 0, 0)
    return rec_dls(node, limit)
```

and also the State class:

```
class State: 
    def __init__(self, state, parent, depth, cost): 
        self.state = state 
        self.parent = parent 
        self.depth = depth 
        self.cost = cost 
        if self.state: 
            self.map = ''.join(str(e) for e in self.state) 
            
    def __eq__(self, other): 
        return self.map == other.map 
    def __lt__(self, other): 
        return self.map < other.map
```

this is the error i have in more details:

[image]

for reference, i am basing the logic of my work on this (from "Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach"):

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample `initial_state` in your code? I am sorry, but I am not very familiar with the 6-puzzle problem.

Comment: In `result == cutoff`, `cutoff` is an int, not a `State`. Did you mean to compare ints or `State`s there?

Comment: but the rec_dls function returns an int as error if a cutoff is reached or if no goal node was found @Carcigenicate

Comment: initial_state = [1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 5]
goal_state = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   @biqarboy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't when `rec_dls` returns an `int`.  It's when it returns one of your `State` objects.

Consider the following lines of code:

```py
           result = rec_dls(child, limit - 1)
           if result == cutoff:
               # ...
```

Suppose `rec_dls` here returns one of your `State` objects.  You then compare your `State` object against `cutoff`, which contains the `int` value `0`, and because you override `__eq__` in your `State` class, this comparison causes `State.__eq__` to be called with `other` set to `0`.

Being an `int`, `0` doesn't have a `map` attribute, hence your error.

Perhaps you want to include in your `__eq__` method a check that `other` is another `State` object:

```
    def __eq__(self, other): 
        return isinstance(other, State) and self.map == other.map
```